# error when trying to send SMS from Signalwire API from FusionPBX software

Tags: php, linux, api, fusionpbx, signalwire-api

```
<?php
    //use SignalWire\Rest;
    
     include "/var/www/fusionpbx/app/messages/SignalWire/src/Rest/Client.php";
      $client = new Client('fc117c36-f3a3-45b1-8abf-cac52fa3355g', 'PT646f3c5a75ae162e3a403fba47455c7c07d27567992c9c51',array("signalwireSpaceUrl" => "logic.signalwire.com"));
       $message = $client->messages
                    ->create("+1(224)6785199",
                             array("from" => "+1(989)2780838", "body" => "Hello World!")
                    );

       print($message->sid);
    
?>
```

I also installed composer and cloned repository from https://github.com/signalwire/signalwire-php

```
myerror was Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Client' not found in /var/www/fusionpbx/app/messages/message_sms.php:33 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/fusionpbx/app/messages/message_sms.php on line 33
```

please help me .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `Client` class is not being found because you're attempting to load the SDK via an `include`. Instead of cloning the repository, simply integrate it with composer.

```
composer require signalwire/signalwire
```

You can read more documentation about setting up the [PHP Relay SDK here](https://docs.signalwire.com/topics/relay-sdk-php/v2/#relay-sdk-for-php-using-the-sdk-relay-client), where you'll find full working examples.